# Delete extra space between first two UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have the following collectionView:

[image]

My problem is that an extra space appear between first two blue cells. I need exactly same space like between two cells in second row.
My `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 7
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 7
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/1JyI4j5C.png Tap collection view, in size inspector change values in "section inspect" left and right. It worked for me, check image as reference

Comment: @niravdesai21 it does't work for me.

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/1JzyxziV.png please mention same values given here.
The image is from the live project the output will be http://pasteboard.co/1JzHNiop.png

Comment: what layout are you using?